# How to import CSV .Import first x amount of rows into one Sheet and then x numbers in next ect

Tags: excel, vba, csv, row, limit

I have a CSV file that gets generated with anything from 6 to 50 
lines in it . I'm able to import it using a VBA macro into one sheet .

But what I'm needing to do is limit the amount of lines per sheet that the macro will import .If it exceeds the max row it copies that sheet and then imports the next x lines into that copied sheet .

This will continue until the end of the csv file.

```
          Sub Import_log()

       With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & GetFile, Destination:=Range("a7"))
       .Name = "logexportdata"
          .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
       .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
       .PreserveFormatting = True
       .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
       .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
       .SavePassword = False
       .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = False
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
       .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
       .TextFilePlatform = 437
       .TextFileStartRow = 2
       .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
       .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)
.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False




  End With
    End Sub


   Function GetFile() As String
    Dim filename__path As Variant
  filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Csv (*.CSV), 
   *.CSV", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
   If filename__path = False Then Exit Function
  GetFile = filename__path
   End Function
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Post the VBA macro you are having.

Comment: Post your code as because if you have write a program to import CSV to an excel file then i think you can also do it easily. At the time of import you can add a condition and a counter to fulfill this.